# Android Implement Play and Download Buttons to Download MP3 files from Firebase Storage using URL's stored in JSON and Uploaded to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a android app with Recylerview to retrieve list of mp3 files with play and download buttons.

Below is my JSON file :

[image: JSON file]

From the above Json file Image, i want to retrieve those audioLink's in recycler view. I want to play them using Mediaplayer along with a seek bar and also Download them to mobile storage, i don't know how to implement them.Please Help me to code

Here is my Screenshot of a audio item in recyclerview

[image: Screenshot of a audio item]
Here is my Model Class of Audio Items

```
public class AudioItem {


public String imageLink;
public String categoryId;
public String number;
public long viewCount;
public String audioTitle;



public AudioItem() {
}

public AudioItem(String imageLink, String categoryId, String audioTitle) {
    this.imageLink = imageLink;
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.audioTitle = audioTitle;

}

public String getAudioTitle() {
    return audioTitle;
}

public void setAudioTitle(String audioTitle) {
    this.audioTitle = audioTitle;
}

public AudioItem(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getImageLink() {
    return imageLink;
}

public void setImageLink(String imageLink) {
    this.imageLink = imageLink;
}

public String getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}



public long getViewCount() {
    return viewCount;
}

public void setViewCount(long viewCount) {
    this.viewCount = viewCount;
}
```

}

Here is my List of mp3's AudioItemViewHolder Class

```
public class ListBRViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


ItemClickListener itemClickListener;


public TextView wallpaperVcount,wallpaperVcountlinear,AudioTitle;
public ImageButton play,download;


public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) 
{
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

public ListBRViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    wallpaperVcount=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewCount);
    AudioTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.brtitle);
    download=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_download) ;
    play=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play) ;
 wallpaperVcountlinear(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewCountLinear);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Here is my AudioListView Class

```
public class NewBRList extends AppCompatActivity {

Query query;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AudioItem> options;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AudioItem,ListBRViewHolder> adapter;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

AdView mAdview;

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
//Room Database
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;
RecentsRepository recentsRepository;
FavouritesRepository favouritesRepository;
ImageView image_category;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newbr_list);


    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(Common.CATEGORY_SELECTED);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.listviewlayoutnewbr) ;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

      image_category=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_newbr);


    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_newbr_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    loadBackgroundList();
}



private void loadBackgroundList() {
    query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.STR_WALLPAPER)
            .orderByChild("categoryId").equalTo(Common.CATEGORY_ID_SELECTED);
    options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AudioItem>()
            .setQuery(query,AudioItem.class)
            .build();


    adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AudioItem, ListBRViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListBRViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final AudioItem model) {


            holder.AudioTitle.setText(model.getAudioTitle());
           holder.wallpaperVcountlinear.setText("Views : "+ model.getViewCount());
           holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Toast.makeText(NewBRList.this,"Download Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });

            holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(NewBRList.this,"Play Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public ListBRViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_br_item_linear,parent,false);
            int height=parent.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
            itemView.setMinimumHeight(height);
            return  new ListBRViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    };

    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Please Kindly Help me :)
Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: There is no problem till here,,i don't know how to code to retrieve the mp3 files from firebase database..in the onclick method of play and download buttons i did'nt write any code.Thank You for the reply :)

Comment: In this case, you should try it and come back if something else comes up.

Comment: I tried to write but that doesn't work and i don't know how to use MediaPlayer in android :(

Comment: Show us what you tried.